# Duplicate removal for VBA Word not working effectively

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a program to remove duplicates and everything is working properly. It is just freezing with large data sets i.e. 1 to 2.5 million words.

What is wrong with my approach? Is there a better one?

```
Sub DeleteDuplicateParagraphs()

Dim p1 As Paragraph
Dim p2 As Paragraph
Dim DupCount As Long
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

StartTime = Timer

For Each p1 In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
  If p1.range.Text <> vbCr Then

    For Each p2 In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
      If p1.range.Text = p2.range.Text Then
        DupCount = DupCount + 1
        If p1.range.Text = p2.range.Text And DupCount > 1 Then p2.range.Delete
      End If
    Next p2
  End If
  DupCount = 0
Next p1

SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation
DupCount = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: As for the question *"What is wrong with my approach?"* - You have created a [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) (read it, it shall be very enlightening).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (first add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime to your VBA project):

```vb
Sub DeleteDuplicateParagraphs()
  Dim p As Paragraph
  Dim d As New Scripting.Dictionary
  Dim t As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim StartTime As Single

  StartTime = Timer

  ' collect duplicates
  For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    t = p.Range.Text
    If t <> vbCr Then
      If Not d.Exists(t) Then d.Add t, New Scripting.Dictionary
      d(t).Add d(t).Count + 1, p
    End If
  Next

  ' eliminate duplicates
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each t In d
    For i = 2 To d(t).Count
      d(t)(i).Range.Delete
    Next
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & Round(Timer - StartTime, 2) & " seconds", vbInformation
End Sub
```

This makes use of the fact that the `Scripting.Dictionary` is a hash table that is geared towards very quickly associating unique keys with values. It is therefore very good at spotting duplicate keys. Dictionary keys have to be strings, conveniently we can use the paragraph texts for that.

For values we use more dictionary objects, solely for the fact that they work a lot better than VBA's arrays. In them we collect the references to the actual paragraph instances with the same text.

Actually deleting duplicate paragraphs is a very simple matter afterwards.

---

Note: The duplicate detection part in the above code is very fast. However, if Word becomes unresponsive in large documents then it's in the duplicate removal part, namely because of Word's undo buffer.

The culprit is that the paragraph ranges are deleted one after another, causing Word to build a very large undo buffer. Unfortunately there is no way (that I know of) to either

- delete multiple separate ranges in one step (which would result in only a single entry in the undo buffer), or
- disable the undo buffer altogether from VBA

Calling `UndoClear` periodically in the "eliminate duplicates" loop might help, disabling `ScreenUpdating` is also not a bad idea:

```vb
' eliminate duplicates
Dim x As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each t In d
  x = x + 1
  For i = 2 To d(t).Count
    d(t)(i).Range.Delete
  Next
  If x Mod 50 = 0 Then ActiveDocument.UndoClear
Next
ActiveDocument.UndoClear
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Just wanted to thank you so much for the time and effort you have put in to helping me.

Your idea behind the method is really impressive. I did change the code slightly and would like you to peruse it when you have the time, to see if it is of optimal standard. Again, I truly thank you, the code ran 20 splits faster than the previous and that is not even over a larger data set.

```
   >  Sub DeleteDuplicateParagraphs()
    > 
    >   Dim p As Paragraph 

>     Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  
>         Dim t As Variant   
>     Dim i As Integer   
>     Dim StartTime As Single
    > 
    >   StartTime = Timer
    > 
    >   ' collect duplicates   For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    >     t = p.range.Text
    >     If t <> vbCr Then
    >       If Not d.Exists(t) Then d.Add t, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    >       d(t).Add d(t).Count + 1, p
    >     End If   Next
    > 
    >   ' eliminate duplicates   For Each t In d
    >     For i = 2 To d(t).Count
    >       d(t)(i).range.Delete
    >     Next   Next
    > 
    >   MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & Round(Timer - StartTime,
    > 2) & " seconds", vbInformation
    > 
    > End Sub
```

Comment: General hint: This site is not a forum, please do not post follow-up questions into the answers section. That, and you did not read my answer very thoroughly. Look at the very first paragraph again.

Comment: That said, yes, you can also use `CreateObject`, I'd still recommend a proper library reference, if only for the benefit of getting autocompletion in the VBA IDE. I've also added a note to my answer, check it out.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback bud, I will implement all of what you have said with regards. I wasn't able to read the correspondence thoroughly as I have been super busy, but thank you so much none the less.

Comment: Unfortunately, The macro was not much faster and I will have to go back to the drawing board, I thank you.

Comment: If you find time to ask a question here and somebody finds time to answer, I think you should find time to read it, too, it's only fair. I'm confused. Didn't you say it was 20 times faster?

Comment: Hi there Tomalak, I said it was 20 splits faster, splits is short for split seconds in scientific terms. The macro does work now, the structure you provided works better with high volumes, which is exactly what was needed. Thanks for the help bud

Comment: Ah, I see. I have not heard the term before.