# Adapted Word VBA code running very slowly in Outlook 2016

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I have some MS Word VBA which runs 10x more slowly when adapted to run within Outlook 2016. I'm hoping someone to help me identify why that might be the case. [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562468/duplicate-removal-for-vba-word-not-working-effectively/) developed the VBA code in this question (which deletes all but one duplicated paragraphs in a Word document) which I adapted to be able to be run on a Message in Outlook 2016. My adapted code is below:

```
Public Sub STRIPPER_RepeatedTextParasTomalakSimple()
' Add ref to Word Object library and
' MS Scripting Runtime in VBA Editor, Tools, References
Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim Selection As Word.Selection

Set objInsp = Application.ActiveInspector
Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
Set objWord = objDoc.Application
Set objSel = objWord.Selection

'------- Inserted Modifed Word VBA below ---------
  Dim p As Word.Paragraph        ' In Word VBA was '....As Paragraph'
  Dim d As New Scripting.Dictionary
  Dim t As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim StartTime As Single

  StartTime = Timer

  ' collect duplicates
  For Each p In objDoc.Paragraphs    ' In Word VBA was '...In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    t = p.Range.Text
    If _
        t <> vbCr Then
        If Not d.Exists(t) Then d.Add Key:=t, Item:=New Scripting.Dictionary
        d(t).Add Key:=d(t).Count + 1, Item:=p
    End If
  Next p

  ' eliminate duplicates
  objWord.ScreenUpdating = False     ' In Word VBA was 'Application.Screenupdating = False'

  For Each t In d
    For i = 1 To d(t).Count - 1
        d(t)(i).Range.Delete         ' This line is the bottleneck
      Next i
  Next t
  objWord.ScreenUpdating = True      ' In Word VBA was 'Application.Screenupdating = True'

MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & Round(Timer - StartTime, 2) & " seconds", vbInformation
objUndo.EndCustomRecord
'------- End of Modifed Word VBA above ---------


End Sub
```

Hopefully it is clear that the section denoted 'Inserted Modified Word VBA' is the original Word VBA code with the 4 modifications indicated by remarks beginning 'In Word VBA was.....'. I also added the top section of the code 4xdims and 4xsets to allow the code to run in Outlook.

The original code runs perfectly in Word **2010** x86, and the modified code runs perfectly in Outlook **2016** x86. I am at a loss as to why when run in Outlook it should be so much slower. (In Outlook the Word 2016 Object Library and the MS Scripting Runtime have both been referenced)

[NB: To avoid any confusion I have also posted a question with a similar title on  at [EE.](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29110029/Adapted-Word-VBA-code-running-very-slowly-in-Outlook-2016.html#a42629779) this relates to *different code*. If either post yields useful results I will cross-post in both venues.]

Comment: Code does not compile as `objWord` is an object an not a libary (that is Word) that contains the Paragraph class in  `Dim p As objWord.Paragraph`. It should be `Dim p As Word.Paragraph`. I don't know why the code runs slower (if it does), but maybe the Word inspector in Outlook is slower? Try if is faster when you create a "real" Word instance copy the Text, remove the paragraphs and copy it back to outlook.

Comment: Sorry, my pasting error. I have edited and made your correction.

Comment: Please avoid [cross postings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266053/is-it-ok-to-cross-post-a-question-between-non-stack-exchange-and-stack-exchange) , 
 https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29110029/Adapted-Word-VBA-code-running-very-slowly-in-Outlook-2016.html And why is the code not the same?

Comment: The code runs at c 1/10th speed in Outlook 2016 compared to being run in Word 2010. At your suggestion I opened Word and created a new docx, then copied an email from Outlook into that Docx, then created a New Mail in Outlook, then copied the text from the Docx into the New Mail, then ran the code. No faster.

Comment: Re: cross posting. Yes completely agree. But this posting relates to code originally posted on SE by Tomalak and I think it would have been rude not to have also asked the question here so he/she could see it. The other posting relates to code posted on EE. They both do almost the same thing in different ways.

Comment: Anything else you are hiding? Make it clear that you use different Office versions (O2016/W2010) with bold chars! Bitness is x86 both? I different versions can have different execution time, but don't ask me why! And if cross posting share the link!!

Comment: The code executing in Word does not have the overhead of automating Word. The Outlook code has that overhead, because it's having to pass the work over to Word and wait for results. Code that does automation will never be as fast as code that operates directly. It takes less time for you to reach over and pick up a tool from your workbench yourself than it does for you to explain to someone else what tool you want and wait for them to hand it to you.

Comment: Thoughts: (1) store the Range in d, not the Paragraph, since you only ever use the Range. (2) Run the t and i loops (for deletion) backwards so that you are deleting from the end of the document towards the beginning.  When you delete a range, all the ranges after the deleted text are affected.  (3) Rather than storing a Range at all, store the Start and End and create a range when you want to delete.  That will reduce the overhead of keeping Word objects alive in the Outlook context.

Comment: Ken: thanks, you might be right. CXW: I don't really understand exactly what the 2 lines at the centre of the 'collect duplicates loop do, so it might be hard for me to test your suggestions 1 to 3.

Comment: And, more specifically, regarding the 'eliminate loop I don't know how to reverse the For Each.....Next loop.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered in the comments by Ken White, however I wanted to add it as in answer in case this is ever asked  again. Ken said

" The code executing in Word does not have the overhead of automating Word. The Outlook code has that overhead, because it's having to pass the work over to Word and wait for results. Code that does automation will never be as fast as code that operates directly. It takes less time for you to reach over and pick up a tool from your workbench yourself than it does for you to explain to someone else what tool you want and wait for them to hand it to you."